# Encode video stream using Direct Show

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I want to Encode video stream using H264,I use [H264 DirectShow library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/files/DirectShow/DirectShowFilters/H.264/) to encode the video but I did not work.I have searched but I have not get any result is there any link to help?

Comment: Please before vote down explain why.May this a well known question but for me a new

Answer (score 2):

This is an overly broad question, you need to narrow it down.

Related reading:

- [Encoding with DirectShow filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631690/encoding-with-directshow-filters)
- [Video Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN - DirectShow documentation, you are supposed to duplicated it in C# through DirectShow.NET
- `CapWMV` Sample in DirectShow.NET ("A .NET sample application using the WM ASF Writer filter to create an wmv file")

Comment: I want to use h264 I have looked for and I have already download library [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/files/DirectShow/DirectShowFilters/H.264/ ) but it did not work

Comment: You need to have/use suitable H.264 encoder/compressor packaged, available and registered for use with DirectShow. There is no standard one, it has to be a third party component. Then you insert it as a regular filter into your topology.

Comment: what do you mean by suitable H.264 encoder/compressor packaged? I thought that h.264 is a standard and it is even used by vimeo and youtube  is that right?

Comment: You don't need just H.264. You want H.264 implementation in form factor of DirectShow filter. It is a DirectShow filter that you can integrate into your processing and application based on DirectShow API.

Comment: I have used the library in the link when I tried to import the dlls an error message during the import occur "Please make sure that this is a valid com or assembly" is that what you mean by suitable

Comment: I am searching h264 directShow am I on the right way please help I am new in direct show